# Reading raw image files inside the map method of tensorflow using Rawpy

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, rawpy

I am trying to load various raw (AWR) images inside a TF dataset for training a model. Basically, I initially had 2 lists:

`im1`: This has the image file paths that will be input to the model.

`im2`: This is the expected output.

---

I am creating the dataset as follows:

`ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((im1, im2))`

Now, this dataset would contain all the paths. To load the raw images from the files, I am using a mapping function as follows:

```py
def read_image(im1, im2):
    im1 = rawpy.imread(im1).raw_image_visible.astype(np.float32)
    im2 = rawpy.imread(im2).raw_image_visible.astype(np.float32)
    return im1, im2

ds_train = ds_train.map(read_image)
```

---

This is giving me an error that seems to be associated with the rawpy module:

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
...
AttributeError: in user code:

    File "/tmp/ipykernel_24/2296991765.py", line 6, in read_image  *
        short = rawpy.imread(short).raw_image_visible.astype(np.float32)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rawpy/__init__.py", line 20, in imread  *
        d.open_file(pathOrFile)
    File "rawpy/_rawpy.pyx", line 408, in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.open_file  **
        

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

When I try to extract the string value of the path from `im1` and `im2` using the `.numpy()` method, I get a new error that seems to suggest that the `.numpy()` method doesn't exist:

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
...
AttributeError: in user code:

    File "/tmp/ipykernel_24/2505255456.py", line 6, in read_image  *
        short = rawpy.imread(short.numpy()).raw_image_visible.astype(np.float32)

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

The modification I did to my code was:

```py
def read_image(im1, im2):
    im1= rawpy.imread(im1.numpy()).raw_image_visible.astype(np.float32)  # numpy method added
    im2= rawpy.imread(im2.numpy()).raw_image_visible.astype(np.float32)  # numpy method added
    return short, long

ds_train = ds_train.map(read_image)
```

---

The full code may be seen in this notebook: https://www.kaggle.com/code/rohan843/learning-to-see-in-the-dark-tf2/notebook

Note: In the notebook above, I have used `short` and `long` instead of `im1` and `im2`. The error causing part is currently commented out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use arbitrary functions/modules in a tf.data map method as it runs in Graph mode. For example:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

is related running in Graph mode. You can use `tf.py_function` but this can cause slowdowns.

```
def read_image(short, long):
    
    short_path = short.numpy().decode('utf-8')
    long_path = long.numpy().decode('utf-8')

    with rawpy.imread(short_path) as raw:
        short_array = raw.raw_image_visible.astype(np.float32)
    with rawpy.imread(long_path) as raw:
        long_array = raw.raw_image_visible.astype(np.float32)
    return short_array, long_array

def read_image_wrapper(short, long):
    short_array, long_array = tf.py_function(
        func=read_image, inp=[short, long], Tout=(tf.float32, tf.float32)
    )
    
    # Set shapes manually because TF can not infer this info from a py_function output.
    short_array.set_shape([short_array.shape[0], short_array.shape[1]])
    long_array.set_shape([long_array.shape[0], long_array.shape[1]])

    return short_array, long_array

ds_train = ds_train.map(read_image_wrapper)
ds_val = ds_val.map(read_image_wrapper)
ds_test = ds_test.map(read_image_wrapper)
```

When you use `tf.py_function` you can apply operations on a tf.data pipeline as if it is working in Eager mode.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out this method.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at a few possible approaches, and all seemed to be working fine. Apart from the already presented solutions, I would also like to add this one:

```py
def generator_func_train():
    im1_paths, im2_paths= list_of_im1_paths, list_of_im2_paths
    for im1, im2 in zip(im1_paths, im2_paths):
        yield loading_function(im1), loading_function(im2)

ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generator_func_train, 
    output_signature=(
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 4), dtype=np.float32),   # The dimensions of the first image
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 3), dtype=np.float32)   # The dimensions of the second image
    )
)
```

This uses the generator function to load the dataset. The official docs can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator).